# com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification & [] having trouble with Google Play services

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use autofill from google placesApi and distance/maps from the google maps Api. 
I run into a compatible issue when I add both to my dependencies(version 26.1.0 for places). However, when I tried to fix it by implement cardview for 27.1.1, the map does not show anymore, and says "My App is having trouble with Google Play services".

My dependency is as follow:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // 1. So far, Google Maps work


    // 2. After adding the following code --> Compatibility issue (27.1.1 vs 26.1.0)
    //implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'    


    // 3. After adding the following code upfront --> My app having trouble with Google Play services
    //implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

}


Could someone give me some insights on how I may fix this problem?
Thanks!
```

Comment: Have you tried updating to a newer version of google play services? The version you are using is very old

Comment: I just updated my SDK tools and changed the google plat code to '''implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0''', but it still has incompatible dependencies.